# Convert Java Map in to net.sf.json.JSONArray.JSONArray()

Tags: java, json

How to convert Java Map into net.sf.json.JSONArray.JSONArray()?

```
Map<String, String> linkedHMapDropDownList = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
linkedHMapDropDownList.put("X", "XXX");
linkedHMapDropDownList.put("Y", "YYY");
linkedHMapDropDownList.put("Z", "ZZZ");
```

I am looking something like
    JSONArray array= new JSONArray(linkedHMapDropDownList);

Answer (score 0):

Found the way to convert, thought might be useful for others

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.accumulateAll(linkedHMapDropDownList);

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.add(jsonObj);